# Do I need to install newman on my desktop if I want to run a newman command in Gitlab?

Tags: docker, gitlab, yaml, postman, newman

I'm new to Gitlab, newman and docker, and I'm sort of in a crash course on how to integrate everything together.

On my desktop (Windows OS), I've installed newman, and I have managed to run "newman run [postman collections]" via windows commandline.

What i ultimately want to do is to do run a newman command in Gitlab.
In the .gitlab-ci, I have this:

```
stages:
      - test

Test_A: 
     stage: test
     image: postman/newman
     script:
     - newman run Collection1.json
```

A few questions come to mind:

1. Do I need to also run the "npm install -g newman" command in the .gitlab-ci file?
   If not, how does Gitlab know the syntax of a newman command?
   Example: newman run
2. Do I need to specify in my .gitlab-ci file a command for docker?
   Example: docker pull postman/newman

Update#2

```
stages:
      - test

before_script:
     - npm install -g newman
     - npm install -g npm

Test_A: 
  stage: test
  script: 
    - newman run Collection1.json
```

Comment: You need to install all dependencies in your pipeline in order to run the tests. If your tests are dockerized, you only need to pull the image and run a container with the tests. If your tests are not dockerized, you need to install node and newman.

Comment: Hi @pavelsaman, thank you for the info. Ok, my tests are not dockerized, which means i need to install node and newman in the pipeline. Something like this? Update#2.

Comment: Yes. You can get an inspiration here https://medium.com/@autumn.bom/run-postman-tests-with-newman-in-gitlab-ci-c34bc90e17ec

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to identify is how your GitLab pipelines are executed.

My personal choice is to use Docker-based runner.

If you're using a GitLab docker-runner to run your pipeline then you just have to define your container image in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Here's a tested (on GitLab.com) version of pipeline yml

```
stages:
   - test

run_postman_tests: 
    stage: test
    image: 
      name: postman/newman
      entrypoint: [""] #This overrides the default entrypoint for this image.
    script:
      - newman run postman_collection.json
```